# How to return a widget after few seconds?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
        return
          Container(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child:
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      height: 30,
                      child:
                      RaisedButton(
                        child:
                        Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text("Test"),
                          ],
                        ),
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        elevation: 0,
                        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                        //onPressed: () {
                        //  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ToSchoolScreen()));
                        //},
                      )
                  ),
                ],
              )
          );
```

I have a code like this above.
And i'd like to return a this Container after few seconds later.
But if i use `Future` directly like this

```
        return
            Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
              Container(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  child:
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          height: 30,
                          child:
                          RaisedButton(
                            child:
                            Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text("Test"),
                              ],
                            ),
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            elevation: 0,
                            splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                            //onPressed: () {
                            //  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ToSchoolScreen()));
                            //},
                          )
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
              );
            });
```

i got an error `` type `Future<dynamic> ' is not a subtype of type 'Widget' ``.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you want the framework to display for the first five seconds? Your build should return either the first set of widgets or the second set depending on, say, a bool. Have your future set that bool after 5 seconds - inside setState, of course.

Comment: Sorry, 500ms, not 5 seconds.

Comment: You are returning 'Future.delayed...' you need to return a widget like a Container. Either make it the child of a widget or add a return infront of the Container that's inside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```dart
FutureBuilder(
    future: Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500)),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
// Checks whether the future is resolved, ie the duration is over
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) 
            return MyWidget();
        else 
            return Container(); // Return empty container to avoid build errors
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FutureBuilder` as your parent widget and your future function to return your data after some seconds.
Please go and read docs for future builder
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
testing();
})
```

**create widget method**

```
Widget testing(){
 return
          Container(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child:
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      height: 30,
                      child:
                      RaisedButton(
                        child:
                        Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text("Test"),
                          ],
                        ),
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        elevation: 0,
                        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                        //onPressed: () {
                        //  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ToSchoolScreen()));
                        //},
                      )
                  ),
                ],
              )
          );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

check my code

```
FutureBuilder(
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                  } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    var datta = jsonDecode(snapshot.data.toString())['response'];
                    if (datta.runtimeType == String) {
                      return Container();
                    } else {
                      List<dynamic> data = jsonDecode(snapshot.data.toString())['response'];
                      List<Widget> child = [Container()];
                      if (data.length != 0 && data.length != null && data != []) {
                        data.forEach((f) {
                          Widget wg = TeklifCard(
                            key: UniqueKey(),
                            bransID: 8,
                            onSatinAl: () {
                              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => KartBilgisi()));
                            },
                            prim: '${f['Prim']}₺',
                            teklifNo: '${f['TeklifNoWS']}',
                            sKodu: '${f['SKodu']}',
                          );
                          child.add(wg);
                        });
                      }


                      return Column(
                        key: Key('${Random().nextInt(45847)}'),
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                children: child,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    }
                  } else {
                    return Center(
                      child: Text('Hata'),
                    );
                  }
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              },
              future: getOffers(),
            ),
```